# Same code to search a JTable with RowSorter and RowFilter only works in 2 out of 4 JTables

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm working on a Java GUI project in NetBeans and have two different `JPanels` with `JTables` and a `JTextField` that the user can type into in order to search for items in the JTable.

It looks like this
[image].

When the user types into the `JTextField` the `KeyTyped` event is called which calls my `filterSearchResults()` method. This method makes a new `TableRowSorter` for each of the 4 `JTables` I am working with every time it is called (I know it's inefficient but I am just shooting for something that works at the moment).

The search function works perfectly for the first two tables (jTable1 and jTable2) but does absolutely nothing for the second two even though it seems I'm doing the exact same process for both.

The tables are contained in `jScrollPanes` which are in `jTabbedPanes` in different tabs.

[image]
Here is what the GUI hierarchy looks like.

For `jTable1` and `jTable2` the table updates based on the search query entered in the text field and it looks like this

[image]

When the user types into the text field for the other 2 tables nothing happens. I was under the impression that there was no need to call an update function for the tables and I don't believe that there is an update function called for `JTable1` and `JTable2` at any point.

I can't explain the discrepancy and I don't know why the filtering doesn't appear on the `finalMaleGroupsTable` and `finalFemaleGroupsTable`. The filtering function is as follows:

```java
    //UPDATE JTABLE FROM SEARCH FILTER
    void filterSearchResults(int x){
        firstRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable1.getModel());
        secondRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable2.getModel());
        thirdRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(finalMaleGroupsTable.getModel());
        fourthRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(finalFemaleGroupsTable.getModel());

            String text = jTextField1.getText();
            jTable1.setRowSorter(firstRowSorter);
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    firstRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    firstRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
                
            jTable2.setRowSorter(secondRowSorter);
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    secondRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    secondRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
                
            text = jTextField5.getText();
            finalMaleGroupsTable.setRowSorter(thirdRowSorter);
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    thirdRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    thirdRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
                
                finalFemaleGroupsTable.setRowSorter(fourthRowSorter);
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    fourthRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    fourthRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
        
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged JavaFX?

Comment: What debugging have you done? The first two tables use `jtextField1`. Last two tables use `jtextField5`. Did you actually display the search text that is being used, to make sure it is what you expect?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use meaningful, descriptive names for components, `firstRankedFilterField` is less likely to cause confusion later, than `jTextField1`.